# How to specify the separation between two table multi-columned columns without spoiling their alingments?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

For this MWE, when manually setting the separation between both multi-columned columns, the first set (i.e. `\multicolumn{2}{c}{First}`) doesn't preserve its center alignment as shown in the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cc @{\hspace{10\tabcolsep}} cc}
        \toprule
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{First} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second}\\
        SGL & WSGL& Exponential & Piece-wise\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc  c @{\hspace{10\tabcolsep}} cc}
        \toprule
        &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{First} &&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second}  \\
        & SGL & WSGL                 && Exponential & Piece-wise     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

in your code the `@{\hspace{10\tabcolsep}}` is considered as part of third column (instead `\tabcolsep`), so `multicolumn` is correctly centered. with adding new column your problem is solved.

[image]